# Xpath does not work running (in eclipse) but working on Debug mode as well as Selenium IDE

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

```
selenium.type("search-query", "case");
selenium.click("//div[@id='advanced-search-box']/a[1]");
selenium.click("//table[@id='search-results-table']/tbody/tr[*]/td[2]/a[@class='result-name']");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("case"));
```

Result:

```
com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Element //table[@id='search-results-table']/tbody/tr[*]/td[2]/a[@class='result-name'] not found
```

Comment: And you've verified that the page contains a correct table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does

```
selenium.click("//div[@id='advanced-search-box']/a[1]");
```

do as you are not waiting for a new page to load, or any ajax to happend. If something is happening then you need to wait for it. The reason it would work in debug mode is because you are slowly stepping over each step (and thus there is enough time for anything to happen). It would also work in Selenium IDE because it is not as faster as the JUnit runner.

Comment: Yes. I have tried waitForCondition but yet its failed.... Actually the condition was wrong and using the same command with proper condition it works.. Thanks for your suggestions and valuable comments

Comment: @Unni I am also facing the same problem. You got any solution?